# javascript script works in Firefox, Chrome, Safari, Internet Explorer < 9, but not in IE 9

Tags: javascript, internet-explorer-9

I'm using this script in a website: http://www.dhtmlgoodies.com/index.html?whichScript=quiz-maker

It allows to easily make quizs. The issue is that it works in every browser but IE 9, and I really need to make it work (or at least try).

My problem is that I don't know where to start looking in the code of that script for a solution, and I was hoping that someone could give me a clue or point me in the right direction. Maybe there's a known IE 9 bug that I'm not aware of or something like that.

Here's an example of the same script in a test page that I've made with it: http://s337174121.onlinehome.us/tests/quiz/

Any help would be much appreciated!

Comment: Press F12, click scripts -> start script debugging and then you can now get a more detailed explanation of errors

Comment: http://s337174121.onlinehome.us/tests/quiz/js/dg-count-down.js is 404ing ... might want to fix that first then trouble shoot further.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Your version of MooTools is out of date. It's probable that it's not recognising that IE9 does not support the "hack" of `document.createElement('<input type="radio" name="xyz">')` that older versions of IE were stuck with.

Try updating your copy of MooTools.

Comment: Yeah that was the reason, the mootools version provided was too old, I updated to the last one and works fine :). Thank you very much for your help!

Answer (score -1):

Have a look at the errors reported in F12 developer tools console:

```
SEC7111: HTTPS security is compromised by https://api.twitter.com/xd_receiver.html 
index.html?whichScript=quiz-maker
SCRIPT5022: DOM Exception: INVALID_CHARACTER_ERR (5) 
mootools-1.2.4-core-yc.js, line 122 character 47
```

I would suggest trying to solve those errors first, before progressing.